# How to fix sudo: account validation failure, is your account locked?

Tags: linux, sudo, manjaro

First of all, I want to mention that I am running Manjaro Linux. Today when I wanted to install a new program I got the following error when trying to use sudo pacman:

```
sudo: account validation failure, is your account locked?
```

I googled around a bit and found a few possible causes of this issue, but none of the solutions I found seemed to fix my problem. What I tried so far:

- booting with init=/bin/su and running /usr/bin/passwd
- using chage to check the expiration dates of root and my user account

Another thing which might be important to mention is that I used to authenticate for sudo by using my fingerprint reader. I used fprintd to do this. I thought this might have been the reason for the error so i removed fprintd as well, however this did not resolve the issue. Does anyone have a clue of how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I happened on this error on WSL2+Ubuntu after renaming the default user account name of the WSL container. *Login* was working in the sense that I could run `wsl` from the host and arrive in bash at my home directory within the Ubuntu instance, but `sudo` would fail.

For some reason my `usermod` command hadn't modified `/etc/shadow` and it still had the old account name.

```
oldname:$n$[...]$[...]:18529:0:99999:7:::
```

Solution was to manually correct the file to the correct account name, then `sudo` worked again. If you need root access to do this in WSL2 you can run `wsl -u root` from the host to get a root shell.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by logging in as root by using:

`su -`

After which I examined /etc/pam.d/sudo and saw that my file looked different from the standard file (e.g. it still had some variable which had to do with my fingerprint reader in it). I changed it to look exactly like the default after which sudo worked again!

Comment: That still gives an `Authentication failure`